# yii2 события в контроллерах

Tags: php, yii2, события

Есть два модуля - Comments и Pages со своей структурой, т.е. реализация не стандартная как по умолчанию в Yii2. Соответственно два контроллера

```
class CommentsController extends BaseController
{            
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }
}

Event::on(PagesController::className(), PagesController::EVENT_GET_COMMENTS, 
function ($event) {
       echo 'comments';
    });
```

ну и аналогично для Pages

```
class PagesController extends BaseController
{   
    const EVENT_GET_COMMENTS = '';

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->trigger(self::EVENT_GET_COMMENTS);

        return $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

В теории при вызове контроллера Pages действия `index` должно срабатывать событие `EVENT_GET_COMMENTS` и выводиться `comments`, но этого не происходит :(

Comment: вы уверены, что обработчик вообще ставится? если у вас все подключается по psr, то код файла CommentsController не будет загружен вплоть до явного использования этого CommentsController.

Comment: Собственно в этом и проблема, но как ее решить я не знаю

Comment: Вам необходимо объявить подписку на событие где-то ранее. Смысл объявлять её в контроллере, который даже не будет запускаться при этом событии? И вообще: зачем пытаться с хорошим фреймворкам создавать свои велосипеды и не использовать стандартные решения для подобных вещей?

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть 3 способа:

**№1 (глобально):**

1. Создать компонент с необходимой логикой
2. Добавить в конфигурационный файл

   ```
   'components' => [
       'myComponent' => [
           'class'=>'app\components\MyComponent'
       ],
       //other components
   ]
   ```

   и не забыть про `'bootstrap' => ['log','myComponent']`

**№2:**

Унаследовать метод в контроллере

```
public function beforeAction($event)
{
    // ваш код
    return parent::beforeAction($event);
}
```

**№3:**

1. Создать поведение: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html, см. как
2. Добавить написанное поведение в контроллер, например как AccessControl